# Формула нахождения угла у края страницы работает странно

Tags: javascript, математика, формулы

Решил сделать что-то простенькое типа, когда двигается мышка меняется угол поворота у квадрата. Потом добавил, когда зажимаешь мышь он увеличивается в размерах, так же поворачивается. И в этом режиме, когда уводишь мышку в самый левый или правый край, формула вычисления угла начинает работать странно(попробуйте так сделать, поймете). Как устранить проблему?

Так же плюсом было бы рассказать, как работают формула нахождения угла и объяснить почему, когда умножаешь переменную dist (в том режиме увеличения размеров) на корень из двух, формула начинает работать нормально(уберете строчку, поймете).

код:

```html
<html>
  <head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <style>
  :root {
   --rotate:0rad;
   --h: 200px;
  }
  body {
   margin: 0;
  }
  .outer {
   display: flex;
   height: 100vh;
   max-height: 100vh;
   overflow:hidden;
   width: 100%;
  }
  .div {
   text-align: center;
   margin: auto;
   height: var(--h);
   width: var(--h);
   background-color: grey;
   transform: rotate(var(--rotate));
  }
  .div p {
   color: #fff;
   margin-top: 0;
   font:30px Sans-serif;
  }
  .div p::after {
   content: 'eE'
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="outer">
  <div class="div"><p></p></div>
  <script>

   w = window.innerWidth,
   h = window.innerHeight;
   var f = Math.sqrt(2)

  function checkDist(x1,y1,x2,y2) {
   return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x1 - x2, 2) + Math.pow(y1 - y2, 2))
  }
  
   var div = document.querySelector('.div')
   var divH = div.scrollHeight
   var divHover = false
   var PI = Math.PI
   
   div.onmouseover = e=>{
    divHover=true
   }
   div.onmouseout = ()=>{divHover=false}
   document.addEventListener('mousedown', e=>{
     document.onmousemove = e=>{
     rads = Math.atan2(e.y-h/2, e.x-w/2)+PI/2+PI/4

     dist = checkDist(e.x,e.y,w/2,h/2)*f+f
      
     degs = Math.round(180/PI*rads);

     document.querySelector(':root').style.setProperty('--rotate', degs+'deg')
     document.querySelector(':root').style.setProperty('--h', dist+'px')
     }
   })
   document.addEventListener('mouseup', ()=>{document.onmousemove = undefined})

   document.addEventListener('mousemove', e=>{

    if(!divHover) {
     rads = Math.atan2(e.y-h/2, e.x-w/2)+PI/2
     degs = Math.round(180/PI*rads);
     

     document.querySelector(':root').style.setProperty('--rotate', degs+'deg')
     //document.body.style.setProperty('--rotate', rads+'rad')
    }
   })
  </script>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Формула вычисления угла работает правильно.

А вот центр рисуемого квадрата при превышении размера смещается вниз, а не остаётся в центре окна рисования

Расстояние от центра до мышки есть половинка **диагонали** квадрата, а для получения **стороны** квадрата нужно её умножить на корень из двойки - это правильно.

Comment: А почему? И как тогда узнать на какое расстояние он смещается, чтобы можно было потом прописать: transform: translate(...)?

Comment: А где задаётся его положение и преобразование? Я так понимаю, это элемент div с цветом gray - но как именно модифицируется преобразование?

Comment: Да это серый див. Я написал ему margin: auto, то есть в центре(положение).  А преобразование нахожу аркгангенс мыши и центра(поворот), создал функцию чекдист, которая возвращает дистанцию, но почему дистанция не правильно вычисляется, и приходится умножать на корень из двух(высота, ширина). И все значения сохраняются в css переменную. Все преобразования в теге скрипт.

Comment: Про дистанцию написал. Про смещение - мне неясно, относительно чего производится вращение - т.е. явные вычисления делаются относительно w/2, h/2, а скрытые - не знаю.

Comment: Да, спасибо, что объяснил про дистанцию. Не знаю влияет ли это как-то на  поворот(скорее всего не влияет), но после 315 градусов, градусы идут в минус, то есть -45 и т.д до 0 .... Кстати так и не понял, что за скрытые вычисления?

Comment: Скрытые вычисления - преобразования координат, которые каким-то образом зависят от margin и других параметров. atan2 возвращает результат в диапазоне -180..+180, к этому ты прибавляешь 135, вот и получается 315. На правильность поворота не влияет.